# query to set currency mysql

Tags: mysql

I have financial data, and save it in integer, like 1000000000, and I want it display 1,000,000,000 so it's easier to read, how can I do that?

I've tried something like

```
SELECT to_char(col_name, 'Rp 99,999.00') salary FROM my_table
```

but it say function to_char does not exist? 
(Rp) is the official currency of my country,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CONCAT('Rp ',FORMAT(col_name,2)) AS salary

Answer (score 0):

SELECT FORMAT(salary,0) FROM my_table;